# Is there an approved deployment state for Google Actions?

Tags: actions-on-google

I want to get the action approved but want to wait before final distribution/ deployment.

Is this possible or does it go straight to publication once Google approves it?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please make your question a [mcve]. Also check [ask] to make your post answerable.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Beta release. Since the closed beta version has passed Google review, you can elect to make it public at any time without another review by Google:
https://developers.google.com/actions/deploy/release-environments